# MS Access SQL If Then statement for check boxes

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to get a search query to run.  It is as follows.  The last two lines of code do not work.  It is a check box.  If the checkboxYes is checked then pull only the items in the YES/NO field of the database that are checked.  If the checkboxNo is checked then pull only the items in the YEs/No field of the database that are checked.  If BOTH boxes are checked, then pull all items.  I cannot get either scenario to work.  All other fields except the check boxes work correctly.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM NLog
 Where
(([Forms]![FrmSearch]![Combo13] is Null) OR ((NLog.State)=[Forms]![FrmSearch]![Combo13])) and

(([Forms]![FrmSearch]![daterecsrt] is Null) or (((NLog.DateRec) Between [Forms]![FrmSearch]![daterecsrt] And [Forms]![FrmSearch]![daterecend]))) and

(([Forms]![FrmSearch]![datesrttxt3] is Null) or (((NLog.DateRec) Between [Forms]![FrmSearch]![datesrttxt3] And [Forms]![FrmSearch]![dateendtxt3]))) and

(([Forms]![FrmSearch]![checkyes] is Null) or  ((NLog.Compchk)=True)) and

(([Forms]![FrmSearch]![checkNo] is Null) or  ((NLog.Compchk)=False))
```

Thank you!

I am using MS Acess 2010.  This is using the boxes on a form to run the query.

Comment: Where are you running this query from?

Comment: Ms Access 2010.  There is a button on the Form that says "run Query"

Comment: Can you update your question to show the code where you are running the query?

Comment: I don't understand. That is the code for the Query.  It is fulling information from a form with unbound fields.  I have not used VBA for this form, although I have used it in the past.

Comment: what happens when you hit the button, do you have a docmd that opens a query?

Comment: it's just a macros to open the query.  It basically refreshes and open the query

Answer (score 0):

`NLog` is a table so why are you referencing fields in the table as `[Forms]![FrmSearch]![Combo13]` and etc. Those are controls on a form and not fields in your table.  Shouldn't your query really be:

```
SELECT * FROM NLog WHERE
(NLog.State is Null OR NLog.State = Forms!FrmSearch!Combo13)
AND (NLog.DateRec is Null OR NLog.DateRec Between Forms!FrmSearch!daterecsrt And Forms!FrmSearch!daterecend
AND (NLog.DateRec is Null OR NLog.DateRec Between Forms!FrmSearch!datesrttxt3 And Forms!FrmSearch!dateendtxt3) 
AND (NLog.Compchk is Null OR  NLog.Compchk = True) 
AND (NLog.Compchk is Null OR NLog.Compchk = False)
```

Also, the following will not give you any results:

```
AND (NLog.Compchk is Null OR NLog.Compchk = True) 
AND (NLog.Compchk is Null OR NLog.Compchk = False)
```

`NLog.Compchk` can not be both `True` and `False`.  It is going to be one or the other or `Null`.

You will need to check if the boxes are checked and build the last part of your query around that, (ie `IIF()`).